# how to store a list in a single array index

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, list, indexing

How to store a complete list in a single array index?

```
ip[x]=[1,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,1,1]

def fitness(c)
      ..
      ..
      return

for x in range(0, 100):
    print 'chromosome%d'%(x+1)
    c=[randint(1,3) for y in range(10)]
    fitness(c)
    ip[x]=c
```

Comment: Exactly that way: Python is dynamically typed so you can store *anything* in an array.

Comment: Or any other way to achieve it so that i can able to access each list specifically

Comment: Can anyone answer it soon?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want. As Willem told you in the comments, you can store anything in an array. Are you trying to do something like that ?

```
import numpy as np

L = []

for x in range(11):
    c=[np.random.randint(1,4) for y in range(10)]
    L.append(c)

array = np.array(L)

print array
```

Here is the result:

```
[[1 2 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2]
 [2 1 2 3 1 3 1 3 3 2]
 [3 3 2 3 1 2 2 1 2 3]
 [1 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1]
 [2 2 2 2 3 1 2 1 3 2]
 [1 3 1 1 1 2 3 1 3 3]
 [1 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 2]
 [3 2 1 3 2 3 1 1 1 3]
 [3 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 2]
 [2 3 2 2 3 2 3 2 1 3]
 [1 2 2 3 3 1 3 3 1 1]]
```

**EDIT:** Or something like that ?

```
import numpy as np

L1 = []

L2 = []


for j in range(3):
    for i in range(3):
        c = [np.random.randint(1,4) for y in range(10)]
        L2.append(c)
    L1.append(L2)
    L2 = []

print np.array(L1)
```

Here is the result:

```
[[[1 3 3 2 1 3 2 1 1 3]
  [3 2 2 1 1 1 2 3 3 1]
  [1 2 3 3 1 1 3 1 1 2]]

 [[3 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 1]
  [1 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 2]
  [2 3 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3]]

 [[1 3 3 1 3 2 3 1 2 3]
  [3 3 2 3 3 3 1 2 3 2]
  [2 3 3 2 2 1 3 1 1 3]]]
```